# NetSuite: Cross domain issue while calling to RESTlet from online form

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have an online form to collect user's information.
In this form, I would like to make a call to NetSuite to get data.
I built a call to RESTlet with 'Authorization' on header, test this script by using postman and it works correctly
However when I do same thing on Online form (client script, call https.get() to RESTlet with valid header contain 'Authorization') It's return error "error code: INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT" (none-sense error). I take 2 days to research why it's happening and found the issue is cross domain (i tried to call to RESTlet by using $.ajax and find issue).

Now, I would like to know how to pass "cross domain" issue while calling from online form.

What is best solution to call to NetSuite to get data from online form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if you were able to get around the CORS restriction, if call a Restlet from client side code that is a massive security problem because you are exposing your authorization token to end users.

A good approach is to "proxy" your Restlet using middleware such as a serverless function (like a Google Cloud Function, AWS Lambda etc.). This will solve both the CORS issue and keeping your credentials secure.

Comment: Actually, the security is not an issue. Restlet required 'Authorization' header and this authentication is depend on role setting on Netsuite. And the end user can not access to the Restlet code from server side (if i correct). So Restlet is secure enough to call from out side Netsuite (in this case, i call from online form, not really "out side")

Comment: Please help me to make a call from online from to Netsuite without using any third party tool. Thanks